# How to use playerctl with mpd to control music with the media keys for mpd and other players

Tags: linux, media, mpd

I used to have my media keys bound to prev/next/pause with i3 like so

```
bindsym XF86AudioPrev exec --no-startup-id mpc prev
```

But I wanted to also use other players so I set it to

```
bindsym XF86AudioPlay         exec --no-startup-id playerctl play-pause
```

which runs via the D-Bus and controls all media players that follow the MPRIS Spec [readme](https://github.com/acrisci/playerctl)

So is there a MPRIS module for mpd or an adapter that runs as a service and translates the mpris signals for the mpd? I couldn't find any, but it would be nice to use the media keys for both, not just for one XOR the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MPRIS v2 gateway for mpd is [mpDris2](https://github.com/eonpatapon/mpDris2).

*(I'm affiliated with the project, but I don't know of any other software which implements MPRIS v2, only one for the obsolete and incompatible MPRIS v1.)*

Comment: I added a configuration as file as described in the README and it worked like a charm! The application doesn't run as a service so I also added a line to autostart it with i3. Thank you

Comment: mpDris2 cannot be a system service, because MPRIS is provided on the session bus (which is individual for each session). You could run it as a `systemd --user` service if your distro chose the "user bus" model, but it's easiest to consider it a desktop/session service.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to mpDris2, I'd recommend: [mpd-mpris](https://github.com/natsukagami/mpd-mpris). It is an implementation of the same idea but in [Golang](http://golang.org/) and not in Python and thus it is much lighter and it doesn't have runtime dependencies.